# Play Framework finding the wrong routes file when compiling

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, routes, playframework-2.0

Whenever I start my machine and run `play run` to start my localhost for development the code fails to compile because it goes to the wrong routes file (the one from the directory of the previous project that I had copied the code from). When I run `play clean-all` and restart the play framework it recompiles to the correct routes file. Is there a config file that I can change to make sure that my project compiles with all of the files from the correct directory every time?

Basically the correct routes file is in `C:/.../pastedProject/conf`

I copied the code for this project from another project `C:/.../copiedFromProject/`

The problem is that play is trying to compile with the routes file from the `C:/.../copiedFromProject/` project

I am using intellij 13.1

Comment: @biesior I tried providing a little more detail. I can't post too much if the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that there were iml files left over from when I pasted the old code to the new directory. The fix is to delete the old change the title in the project structure and delete the old iml files. Then rebuild the project files in cmd using either `play idea` or `sbt idea`

Answer (score 0):

Not much information here.   But, if I were to guess: I would only have one project open in your IDE/IntelliJ.  In other words close the projects you are not working on.  I saw a similar issue in Netbeans 8.0 while debugging.  One other thing to try would be to run from the command prompt, this would eliminate a anomaly in your IntelliJ.  My hunch is an anomaly in IntelliJ, it may be getting a bit confused.

Comment: I am running it from command prompt. I tried changing the .iml file. Unfortunately it's proprietary code and I am an intern

Comment: Figured out the problem see my answer